# Crear Botones de Pausa Stop Rec con GTK y OpenCV

Tags: python, botón, opencv, gtk

necesito su ayuda para un problema que me surge: tengo el siguiente código donde mi camara web se activa y comienza a grabar sin nigun problema.

Pero necesito crear tres botones: Grabar, Pausar y Parar, con GTK, pero no se cómo puedo hacerlo. Adjunto el código

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import gtk



def show_webcam(mirror=False):


    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    frame_width = int(cam.get(3))
    frame_height = int(cam.get(4))


    filename = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S") + ".avi"
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename,fourcc, 30, (frame_width,frame_height))

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        while True:
            ret_val, img = cam.read()
            if mirror: 
                img = cv2.flip(img, 1)

            cv2.imshow('Grabacion de Audiencias', img)
            out.write(img)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27: 
                break  # esc to quit
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
        pass

    cam.release()        
    out.release()        
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    show_webcam(mirror=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Espero su ayuda ya que es para un proyecto y no he logrado nada.

---

He logrado que por medio del teclado se pause el vídeo y continue la grabación, además le informa al usuario con señales visuales, pero no he logrado crear estas acciones por medio de bonotes, usando GTK para que el usuario final pueda grabar sin problema. Espero su ayuda.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import gtk
import keyboard
flagrecord=True


def show_webcam(flagrecord):

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    frame_width = int(cam.get(3))
    frame_height = int(cam.get(4))
    FONT = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    filename = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S") + ".avi"

    out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename,fourcc, 30, (frame_width,frame_height))

    while True:
        ret_val, img = cam.read()
        title = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d*%H:%M:%S")
        if flagrecord: 
            img = cv2.flip(img,1)
            cv2.putText(img, "REC", (40,40), FONT, 3 , (0,0,255), 2)
            cv2.circle(img, (20,20), 10 , (0,0,255), -1)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (30,430),(600,480),(0,0,0), -1)
            cv2.putText(img, title, (40,470), FONT, 3 , (255,255,255), 2)
            cv2.imshow('Grabacion de Audiencias', img)
            out.write(img)
        else:
            img = cv2.flip(img,1)
            cv2.putText(img, "PAUSE", (40,40), FONT, 3 , (255,0,0), 2)
            cv2.circle(img, (20,20), 10 , (255,0,0), -1)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (50,430),(570,480),(0,0,0), -1)
            cv2.putText(img, "Audiencias En Pausa", (60,470), FONT, 3 , (255,255,255), 2)
            cv2.imshow('Grabacion de Audiencias', img)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27: 
            break  
        if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
            flagrecord=False
        if keyboard.is_pressed('c'):
            flagrecord=True 
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            break     

    cam.release()        
    out.release()        
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    show_webcam(mirror=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hola Mikey ¿GTK o Tkinter? Porque son dos frameworks completamente distintos, en el título mencionas Tkinter pero en el cuerpo GTK... Si es GTK supongo que usarás [PyGObjects](https://pypi.org/project/PyGObject/) ¿No?

Comment: Hola ofrezco disculpas por la confucion es con gtk, no tengo muy claro como debo hacer para crear los tres botones de REC, PAUSE Y STOP, para ser mas claro ya que puedo que la camara haga lo que deseo pero no se como realizar este paso

Comment: Hola he agregado el código de mis avances espero que alguien me pueda ayudar para crear los botones por medio de gtk

Comment: @mikey Aún no tengo demasiado claro cuál es tu inconveniente, ¿no puedes agregar esas señales a los botones?, ¿ese es el problema?. En sí ¿cuál es el inconveniente?.

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por tu respuesta ese es el inconveniente que no se como agregar esa señal a los botones, pero la idea no es que funcione con el teclado si no con botones creados con GTK para que el usuario haga click con el mouse y no con el teclado